# Find the largest value of $a = x^2 - y^2 + 2xy$, for real numbers $x, y$ such that $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Find the largest value of $a = x^2 - y^2 + 2xy$, for real numbers $x,y$ such that $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$

Here's what I did, but it doesn't look quite convincing to me.

$a = x^2 - y^2 + 2xy = 2x^2 - (x - y)^2 \leq 2x^2 $

The equality occurs when $x = y$.

However, $x^2 + y^2 \leq 1$. When $x = y$, this becomes $2x^2 \leq 1$

Thus, $a \leq 1$, and $a = 1$ occurs when $x = y = \pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

I hope someone could give me some feedback and perhaps also a more rigorous argument.

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier if the maxima is at $x^2+y^2=1$ and at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)#Several_variables if $x^2+y^2<1$ (as that is an open set)

Comment: @watertrainer thank you very much for the pointers! I believe my upcoming calculus classes will cover these topics in the next semester, so I'll definitely take a look at them soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably the easiest way to use polar coordinates for $x$ and $y$.

Let $ x= \rho \cos \phi , y = \rho \sin \phi , 0 \le \rho \le 1, \phi \in [0, 2\pi ) $

Then

$ a = \rho^2 ( \cos^2 \phi - \sin^2 \phi + 2 \cos \phi \sin \phi) = \rho^2 (\cos(2 \phi) + \sin(2 \phi) ) $

This can be written as

$ a = \sqrt{2} \rho^2 ( \cos(\dfrac{\pi}{4} ) \cos(2 \phi) + \sin(\dfrac{\pi}{4}) \sin(2 \phi) ) $

And finally,

$ a = \sqrt{2} \rho^2 \cos(2 \phi - \dfrac{\pi}{4} ) $

This shifted $\cos$ as a maximum at $ 2 \phi = \dfrac{\pi}{4} $, i.e. $\phi =  \dfrac{\pi}{8} $

And also, we have to choose $ \rho = 1$ to maximize $a$.

Therefore, the maximum $a = \sqrt{2} $

And it occurs at $ x = \cos(\dfrac{\pi}{8} ) , y = \sin (\dfrac{\pi}{8}) $

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! I have a question. It seems we just need $ρ^2 \leq 1%$. So it seems more general to me to define that $-1 \leq ρ \leq 1$. Is it ok? If it is, what might be a disadvantage of defining $ρ$ like this? Thank you again!

Comment: There is no point in letting $\rho$ be negative in this problem, because we can get the same point if we shift $\phi$ by $\pi$.

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an elementary solution.

If $x = 0$, $a(0,y) =-y^2 \le  0$ and for $(x,y)=(0,0)$  $a(0,0) = 0$. So,

- $a_{\max }$ is a least greater than $0$, that is $a_{\max }\ge a(0,0) = 0$
- it suffices to find the maximum for the case $x \ne 0$ (as for $x =0$, $a$ is negative)

From the condition $x^2 + y^2 \le 1$, and by denoting $t = y/x$ we have:
$$\frac{x^2 -y^2 +2xy}{x^2 +y^2} \ge a \implies \frac{1-t^2+2t}{1+t^2} \ge a \implies (a+1)t^2 -2t+(a-1)\le 0 \tag{1}$$

For $a\ge 0$, the term $(a+1) \ge 0$, then the quadratic inequality $(1)$ has solution if and only if the Discriminant $\Delta' = 1-(a+1)(a-1)=2-a^2 $ is non negative. That means
$$-\sqrt{2}\le a \le \sqrt{2} $$

So, $a$ reaches its maximum $\sqrt{2}$ if and only if $\cases{x^2 + y^2 = 1\\ t = \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{2}}} \iff$ $(x,y) = \left(\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2} \right)$ or $(x,y)=\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}}{2},-\frac{\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2}}}{2} \right)$.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! Your approach looks very interesting. I'm trying to reproduce it myself to better understand it! Once done, I'll let you know if I have any questions. Thank you again!

Comment: You have a typo in the inequality from the discriminant. It should be $-\sqrt 2 \le a \le \sqrt 2$.